# Java nio no-blocking Client server application and custom protocol

Tags: java, sockets, nio, nonblocking, custom-protocol

I’m working on java.nio no-blocking client server application, the application has a very easy custom protocol as:

```
MyApplcationProtocol:
int lenpalcket;
int filedone;
String Description
byte[] myBodyProtcol
```

(the body length is not fixed.)

The problem is that sometime I don’t have enough byte inside ByteBuffer and then the decode fail

```
while (myByteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
   Utils.fillMyClass(myclass,myByteBuffer);

public void fillMyClass(myclass,myByteBuffer){
   myclass.filedone = myByteBuffer.getInt();
   ...
   int bodyLen = myByteBuffer.getInt();
   byte[] bodyByte = new byte[bodyLen];
   myByteBuffer.get(bodyByte);
   ...
}
```

I have to wait the next buffer to complete  fill the class, so I want to avoid to put a sleep because it blocks the thread. 
Is there a pattern/way/link/example to solve this problem?

I tried also to store the “unread bytes” in a temp buffer, but I don’t like it, and sometimes i doesn’t work correctly.

Thank you, any help is appreciated

Comment: `the body length is not fixed.` Can you think about the largest possible packet? I read somewhere a while ago that you should always create a buffer as big as the largest possible packet. It's not fixed/needs to be split to avoid empty bytes but you would always be sure to have enough space for your largest possible packet

Comment: You need context and state in the socket class.  This is inherent when handling protocols on top of TCP in non-blocking designs.  TBH, byte-by-byte state-machines for protocols are not a bad idea in thread-per connections servers either.